# Unable to get JSON from Ajax POST using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, post

I am sending JSON in a POST to my PHP script. I'm unable to get the object values from the JSON. The format of the POST is as follows:

> [{"name":"amount","value":"12"}]

**Javascript**

```
("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

      var url = "post.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
      var formData = JSON.stringify($("#idForm").serializeArray());
      alert(formData);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(dataresponse) {
          document.getElementById("orderamount").innerHTML = dataresponse.orderamount;
        }
      });
```

**PHP**

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

$data = array();

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$data['orderamount'] = $json['amount'];
//this works 
//$data['orderamount'] = '12345';

echo json_encode($data); 
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible problems: 1) try to console.log(formData) and check if it is correct. 2) console.log(dataresponse) and check if it is correct to access data through dataresponse.orderamount. 3) in PHP, check if you are truly joining the if, perhaps logging stuff in a .txt or .html file to keep track of what is happening (use file_put_contents). In all these cases, the javascript console is your best friend, it usually tells you what is NOT working, or what it is getting back as a response. PHP doesn't though (not directly through an AJAX request), hence take care of the third point aswell.

Comment: see @swap 's answer below. You json has syntax of an array that may contain many name/value tuples.  Treat it as an array.

Comment: Web console wasn't much help. I wrote the contents from the PHP scripts to a txt file. Output is - a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"amount";s:5:"value";s:2:"12";}}

Answer (score 1):

We can parse JSON Array, and dictionaries inside it, like this,

```
<?php
$json = "[{\"name\":\"amount\",\"value\":\"12\"}]";
$dec = json_decode($json,true);

for($idx = 0; $idx < count($dec); $idx++){
    $obj = (Array)$dec[$idx];
    echo $obj["name"];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example json there are two parameters, name and value.

> [{"name":"amount","value":"12"}]

You should use `$json['name']` instead of `$json['amount']`. You can try the following example

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$data = array();
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if($json['name']=='amount') {
$data['orderamount'] = $json['value'];
}
echo json_encode($data); 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try before send the request

```
 setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: It isn't application/x-www-form-urlencoded data, it is JSON.

Answer (score -2):

In Response

document.getElementById("orderamount").innerHTML = dataresponse['orderamount'];